# Restore colors after Android update

Tags: updates, sony-xperia

I bought an Xperia t two weeks ago.
When I plugged it today, I've been asked to update Android, what I did..

Now the sms "chat" changed color and display format.. many other things changed color and format too.

How can I put it back like it was before? I tryed changing the theme, it didn't work.

Is it a change from Android or is it a configuration problem?

Does android always change colors and everything? Everything had a dark/black background before, it's now all white, blue and purple...... I liked it dark

Thank you!

Comment: Which was your previously version and which is your new version?

Comment: This is because you probably moved to 4.X from lower. Welcome to [Holo UI](http://developer.android.com/design/get-started/ui-overview.html)

Comment: I'm now on 4.1.2, I don't know where to see which one I upgaded from